# How do I mock a Dialog service method which displays a prompt using nunit and moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a dialog service which is being used as:

```
this.dialogService.ShowConfirm(
    async (dialogRes, error) =>
    {
        if (dialogRes == true)
        {
            await Action(win);
        }
    },
    "Prompt message");
```

I tried to set up a callback and mock the way it's being executed:

```
this.mockDialogService
    .Setup(x => x.ShowConfirm(
        It.IsAny<Action<bool, Exception>>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<ContentControl>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((Action<bool, Exception> action) => 
        action.Invoke(true, new Exception()));
```

but doesn't work, throws an exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (`Action<bool, Exception>, string, string, string, ContentControl, string)` cannot invoke callback with parameters `(Action<bool, Exception>)`.

I am stuck with it as I do not know how to proceed with mocking it.

Comment: As the error message says: the method you give in the Callback has not enough parameters. Not ethat even if `ShowConfirm` has default values for a parameter, you still need to list the parameter.

Comment: @KlausGütter so in that case what would go in `Action<bool,Exception>` as I need to provide an value right?

Comment: @KlausGütter I want the default functionality to be implemented by setting dialogRes value, how do i do that

Comment: The method signature seems to be `(Action<bool, Exception>, string, string, string, ContentControl, string)` (i.e.6 parameters) but your callback has only one parameter `(Action<bool, Exception> action)`. Just add the other 5 parameters to your callback.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm not able to figure out how can I call the default call back mocking other parameters

Comment: Just change `Callback((Action<bool, Exception> action) =>` to `Callback((Action<bool, Exception> action, string p2, string p3, string p4, ContentControl p5, string p6) =>`.

Comment: @KlausGütter Cannot define action over there, it gives me syntax error.

Comment: I posted it as answer so you can see the complete code. If you still get a syntax error, please post the exact error.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says: the method you give in the Callback has not enough parameters. Note that even if ShowConfirm has default values for a parameter, you still need to list the parameters:

```
this.mockDialogService
    .Setup(x => x.ShowConfirm(
        It.IsAny<Action<bool, Exception>>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<ContentControl>(), 
        It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((Action<bool, Exception> action, string p2, string p3, string p4, ContentControl p5, string p6) => 
        action.Invoke(true, new Exception()));
```